# Indexing the line as per the counting of characters per line in Notepade++

Tags: indexing, character, notepad++

I want to keep the lines as per the total character per line. Means which line have less character will be on top. 
Ex. 
abcdef
abcabcdefghijk
abcdefgh
abc

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking for... please improve your post.

Comment: Please, add sample input file and expected result.

Comment: Sir, I want that if some line has per line total 15 characters, some has 12 characters, some have 18 characters, in that case, I want to keep on the top which line has 12 characters, then the line which has 15 characters & lasts the line which has 18 characters. Means it will be indexing by the quantity of the characters per line.

Comment: I have a line as per this

Comment: I have a line as per this

1) godrej.com
2) intimespectrum.com
3) alfalaval.com
4) nelco.in

&  I want as per this

1) nelco.in                      ( total 8 characters )
2) godrej.com                  ( total 10 characters )
3) alfalaval.com              ( total 13 characters )
4) intimespectrum.com   ( total 17 characters )

Comment: See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/609028/how-can-i-sort-the-lines-in-a-text-file-by-the-length-of-each-line-in-notepad)